# Change the website title in Google search

Tags: joomla, title, google-search

I am creating a Joomla website(Rockettheme template). The problem is that when I add it into the Google search, the title of the link appears as the name for the Rockettheme template, and I can't change it to the name of my website. Here is a picture of the google search : 
[image]

How can I change the Ximenia-July 2012 Template Demo to the title that I want?

Answer (score 1):

As Super Administrator, you should have access to the Global Configuration, which is where you can update the Site Title.

In the back-end Administration, go to your main Control Panel, go to Global Configuration, and in the first section "Site" there should be a field for "Site Name". Enter the name of your website that you want.

While you're there, you should also scroll down to the Metadata Settings and update your Site Meta Description with a short description of what your site is about, as this is used on the Google Search Engine Results Page as well.

c

Answer (score 1):

*Well I know your feel bro* :)

OK If I guessed it correct,

1. you have to go to the main menu, in menu manager.
2. select 'home' menu item, and then go to 'page display options'
3. there you can find what you seem to looking for, viz the first input box labeled 'Browser Page Title'.

[image]